# How to handle event bubbling on tab slidder ul and li by using class or id selector in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I have tab slidder there are number of anchor link's so,I am try preventdefault , return false , stoppropogation .I want to stop event bubbling by useing jquery.
Here is my HTML part.

```
<div class="ui-slider-tabs-list-wrapper">
    <div class="ui-slider-tabs-list-container">
        <ul class="ui-slider-tabs-list">
            <li class="li-equity">
                <a class="equity" id="equityAnchor_1" href="#equity_1" onclick="abc('');">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="li-equity">
                <a class="equity" id="equityAnchor_2" href="#equity_2" onclick="abc('');">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery code-

```
$("a.ui-slider-tabs-list-wrapper").on("click", function (e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log( 'I was just clicked11!' );
    });
```

I try e.stopPropogation();I try e.preventDefault();I try e.stopImmediatePropogation();Any Help.

Comment: Where have you tried ?

Comment: @my code not in any jquery tool.

Comment: Try `$(".ui-slider-tabs-list-wrapper a")` selector

Comment: Nop, abc function call .

Comment: when and what do you want to prevent?! calling abc function when clicking a link?!  then why do you attach abc to anchors onclick?

Comment: when i click first link then disable all link after complition sucess of response in ajax then it will start propogating.

Comment: are you loading tab contents with ajax? and you want to disable all links till content loading complete, yes?

Comment: u r correct. exactly..